# XML xPath syntax to grab all elements

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

Need to grab from this output : For NameRecomendation : Brand all values and store it to combobox.

Xml output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <GetCategorySpecificsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <Timestamp>2018-10-29T18:44:11.220Z</Timestamp>
      <Ack>Success</Ack>
      <CorrelationID>xxxxx</CorrelationID>
      <Version>1077</Version>
      <Build>E1077_CORE_API6_18790878_R1</Build>
      <Recommendations>
        <CategoryID>10986</CategoryID>
        <NameRecommendation>
          <Name>Brand</Name>
          <ValidationRules>
            <ValueType>Text</ValueType>
            <MaxValues>1</MaxValues>
            <SelectionMode>FreeText</SelectionMode>
            <VariationSpecifics>Disabled</VariationSpecifics>
          </ValidationRules>
          <ValueRecommendation>
            <Value>Unbranded</Value>
            <ValidationRules />
          </ValueRecommendation>
          <ValueRecommendation>
            <Value>Handmade</Value>
            <ValidationRules />
          </ValueRecommendation>
          <ValueRecommendation>
            <Value>Affinity</Value>
            <ValidationRules />
          </ValueRecommendation>
          <ValueRecommendation>
            <Value>Agatha</Value>
    ...
```

But i seem missing something. I tried with using xPath but it just wont show nodes

[xPath documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim MyXML As New XmlDocument()
MyXML.LoadXml(RichTextBox1.Text)
Dim MyXMLNode As XmlNodeList = MyXML.SelectNodes("//*/NameRecommendation")

For Each node In MyXMLNode
    '// add item to comboboxBrand
Next
```

Tried with

```
Dim MyXMLNode As XmlNodeList = MyXML.SelectNodes("//NameRecommendation")
```

Edit :

By going through debugger i actually find that node in xml document

[image]

Comment: How is MyXML being loaded?

Comment: @dbasnett from richtextbox which contains that textabove. Just edited code

Comment: @kjhughes Can't actually find my answer there. This is task with VB.NET and i can't go with strict path i need to find all nodes with..

Comment: Added VB.NET example for you.  Let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: Where did the XML come from?  Did someone type it into the richtextbox?